# Transition при применении hover к text-decoration

Tags: css

Проблема следующая: при применении hover к li элементам transition не работает- свойство изменяется сразу,за исключением color(который меняется с должной задержкой).

```
.content-info-list li {
transition: all 5s:}

<!--Этот код не работает с transition -->

.content-info-list li:nth-child(1){
text-decoration: line-through;
} 
.content-info-list li:nth-child(1):hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

<!--Этот код работает -->

.content-info-list li:nth-child(2) {
    color: #008000;
}

.content-info-list li:nth-child(2):hover {
    color: #d55a5a;
}
```

Работают ли вообще свойства без цифровых значений с transition?
Как применить transition к тексту?

Answer (score 0):

`text-decoration` - является составным свойством, с помощью которого задаются такие свойства как:

- `text-decoration-line`,
- `text-decoration-color`,
- `text-decoration-style`,
- `text-decoration-thickness`

Применение `transition` к составному свойству равносильно его применению ко всем составляющим частям.

В списке [анимируемых свойств](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) можно заметить наличие лишь

- `text-decoration-color`
- `text-decoration-thickness`

В использованном примере эти свойства не задаются, следовательно и transition никак не влияет.

Answer (score 0):

> Работают ли вообще свойства без цифровых значений с transition? Как применить transition к тексту?

любая анимация/переход работает только со свойствами, у которых возможны промежутчные значения.

если это цвет - то да, т.к. между двумя любыми цветами вычислимо промежуточное состояние.

если это text-decoration-line или, например, display - то нет. т.к. в природе не существует промежуточных состояний между их возможными значениями.

ваш вариант - задать свойство как "есть декорация", но анимировать только цвет от прозрачного до нужного.